# Why does systemctl isolate multi-user.target succeed only once?

Tags: systemd, init

[I was just taught here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293084/) that `systemctl isolate multi-user.target` is the modern way to unload the graphic shell, which was done by `init 3` previously.

I see that `init 3` still works in my system but it succeeds only once, likewise `systemctl`. When you run them once, then, it is fine -- the Gnome/KDE is unloaded and you can `startx` again. But, once you did that, initializing to level 3 does not work anymore. I am left at level 5, in KDE, at least in my Fedora-24. `systemctl` just hangs until I kill it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Why is that? Do you notice the same behaviour?

Yes, I run the *go to multi-user* command from the GUI terminal.

Comment: When run the command the second time, did you boot back into the graphical shell before running it again?

Answer (score 5):

You are in runlevel 5 or to be precise in graphical.target. You do runlevel 3 or systemctl isolate multiuser.target.

If you type startx you are still in runlevel 3 or multiuser.target, even if X is running, so systemctl isolate or runlevel 3 will not work.

Comment: According to http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/297835/9689 there is no `multi-user.target` , is it? Otherwise, could someone, please correct example with better target?

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki check `systemctl list-units` and you will see if you have a multi-user target.

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20160823160729/https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd), you can use `set-default` instead of `isolate`:

```
$ sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

Then reboot.